# error parsing wsdl with wsimport

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

When trying to generate classes from https://api.betfair.com/global/v3/BFGlobalService.wsdl with wsimport from JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01 i get this warning:

```
[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'types:LoginReq' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 1841 of file:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/lett/wsdl/BFGlobalService.wsdl#types?schema2

[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'types:LoginReq' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 1841 of file:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/lett/wsdl/BFGlobalService.wsdl#types?schema2
```

What is happening wrong? The file is saved to my disk because when I pass the URL as a parameter it gives-me another error:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Failed to read the WSDL document: https://api.betfair.com/global/v3/BFGlobalService.wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.


[ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 

 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar issue

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'types:LoginReq' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

We can safely ignore the warnings and go ahead.